# selenium 3 deleteAllCookies from edge failed

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I deleted cookies from edge via EdgeDriver, it was failed, any way can fix it?

```
browser.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the answer to this issue also.
See https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/5751773/
Current status (as of 2017-09-20) "FIXED, NOT YET FLIGHTED" - maybe it will get flighted some time soon, along with MS pig squadron.

Comment: I'm using Edge build 15063 but still not fixed. I've posted a question at the link above